# Ledger to pivot table

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a pivot table where I keep track some investment activity. It is organized in a ledger format:

```
Date        Asset   Movement    Value
10-Jan-18   Cash    Initial     5000
15-Jan-18   GE      Buy         500         
20-Feb-18   GE      Buy         800
25-Feb-18   GE      Dividend    50
15-Mar-18   FB      Buy         1000
15-Mar-18   GE      Mark2Market 1500
```

I want to create a non-macro/VBA/GoogleAppsScript pivot table that would look like this:

```
Asset   10-jan-18   15-jan-18   20-feb-18   25-feb-18   15-mar-18
Cash    5000        4500        3700        3750        2750
GE      0           500         1300        1300        1500
FB      0           0           0           0           1000
Total   5000        5000        5000        5050        5250
```

I have tried to build this using auxiliary columns, for the initial table, that calculate the "Cash Flow" and "Asset Flow", that multiply the value using the following auxiliary table.

```
Movement    Cash    Asset
Initial     1       0
Mark2Market 0       1
Dividend    1       0
Buy         -1      1
Sell        1       -1
```

However, those fields do not enable the pivot table to calculate the cash balance on dates on which there is no movement on the cash account. What should be the right spreadsheet architecture to make this work?

Comment: This could be on-topic on [su] for Excel and on [webapps.se] for Google Sheets, but it looks to be off-topic here because it's not clear how it's related to programming.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for posting it on the wrong place. Would you be able to move it to web applications? I can't do it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

With time, I've solved my own question using the steps described below:

On the first, ledger spreadsheet, I've added columns Cash Flow, Asset Flow, Cash Balance and AssetBalance. CashFlow and AssetFlow multiply the Value column by the correspondent Movement table, using vlookup. CashBalance and AssetBalance sums up all CashFlow and AssetFlow columns, respectively, whose date is less than or equal to data of the transaction, and that have the same Asset name.

Then, on a separate spreadsheet, I do a pivot table using Google Apps Script query command:

```
=query({query(Ledger!A:K,"select A, B, C, D, sum(K) where D != 'Cash' group by A, B, C, D",1);
  query(Ledger!A:K,"select A, B, '!Cash', 'Cash', min(J) group by A, B",1)},
    "select Col2, Col3, Col4, sum(Col5) where Col2 != 'Institution' and Col2 != '' group by Col2, Col3, Col4 pivot Col1")
```